# What is the critical diameter ratio of a cone shaped reducer before air overflows

Tags: fluid-dynamics, air

Let's assume we have a cone shaped cylindrical reducer with $D_1$ inlet and $D_2$ outlet diameter (funnel). Air flows through it with velocity $v_1$ at inlet and $v_2$ at outlet.

With the velocity and area of the inlet and the standard properties of air we can determine the airflow $q_1$ with units $\mathrm{ m^3/s}$. I guess that the air overflows if $q_1 > q_2$ because the tube segment with the reduced cross section can't suck enough air.

I am curious about whether it is a simple ratio (in function with air velocity) between $D_1$ and $D_2$ diameters that gives information to avoid too drastic change in cross section causing air overflow.